# Двухуровнеый генератор списка

Tags: python-3.x

Друзья, как мне конструкцию ниже превратить в красивый генератор списка?

```
cnt = int(input())
list=[]
for i in range(0, cnt+1):
    for j in range(0, i):
        list += [i]
```

И/или в чем моя ошибка?

```
list=[[list+=[i] for j in range(0, i)] for i in range(0, cnt)]
```

Comment: Не стоит использовать зарезервированные слова Python в качестве названий для переменный. В данном случае вы использовали зарезервированное слово `list`

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = [x for i in range(int(input()) + 1) for x in [i]*i]
```

или ленивая версия:

```
from itertools import repeat 

it = (x for i in range(int(input()) + 1) for x in repeat(i, i))
```